# Is it possible to make realtime search in MongoDB via mongoose using angular controller with form search query input text?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

At first sorry for my english ..and for someone maybe stupid question but Im new at programming in Angular,Node, Express and mongoDB together...

My question is If it is possible to make something like realtime search in DB . I am writing the query for search on the client side (angular + HTML) the matched result from mongoDB will show somewhere on the page (with number of similar word). I need to do it in the Angular and MongoDB using Node and Express for routing

Example situation: In the browser I will write some word etc. cook and in my database are saved data like (cook, cooker, cooking) ...The result that I would like to show is whole row  of table with Cook and number of similar words with cook in the word so 3 is the answer ...

I would like to know what I have to study,and use for it

HTML would look like this I think ? ..:

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="find()" name="findForm">

   <div class="form-group">
       <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="word"
           ng-model="word" placeholder="search from Mongo" >
   </div>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">search
   </button>
```

But I dont know whats next ...some controller with http post method or what ..? ..

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.post('/api/search', $scope.word)
    $scope.search= function() {
        ({
            -----??
        });
    };
}]);
```

Is it right ? ...should it works ..? ..Last function should be in the server.js file where I have to implement function for find word in my DB..isn it ?

```
app.post('/api/search', function(req, res) {
   Word.find(........)
// here I dont know how ..

});
```

I will be very thankfull if somebody get me some advice how to pass through that ...thanks ..

I m sorry if I dont explain my problem too clear ..if you have some more question what I am lookin for ..ask please ..

THANKS..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to real time search. you can use `RegExp` for partial search. can try this process.

you used `ng-submit="find()"` in your dom so you need a `find` function in controller and from this function call the api:

```
$scope.find = function() {
      $http.post('/api/search', $scope.word).then(function(response) {
        $scope.words = response.data;
        //your code
      });
};
```

and in server side

```
app.post('/api/search', function(req, res) {
      var query = {};
      //generetae query for partial search
      query.word = new RegExp(req.body.word, 'i');// assume word is field name for query.word

        Word.find(query, function(error, words){
          if(error) {
            return res.status(400).send({msg:"error occurred"});
          }
          return res.status(200).send(words);
        });
   });
```

N.B: better to use get verb for search if no problem to show query data

Comment: thanks ...routing now works good I think but HTTP Status 500 error occured with invalid json when I try your code ..dont know whats the problem ... :( ..

Comment: okey solved problem was in content type for post method ...but  I spent 2 days on it :D ..

Answer (score 0):

model ? ..did you mean module ? ..

```
angular.module('SymText')
  .controller('FreeWrtCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.find = function () {
        $http.post('/api/find',$scope.word)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.words = response.data;

        })
    }

}]);
```

And the server-js :

```
app.post('/api/find', function (req, res) {

var query={};
query.word=new RegExp(req.body.word, 'i');

//console.log(req.body.word);
User.find(query, function (err, words) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send({msg:" error during search DB"});
        console.log(words);
        return res.status(200).send(words);

    }
)
```

});

and my model for now in Mongo look like ..:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    fullname: {type: String, required: true},
    role: Number
});
```

..its not the main mongo DB but in that DB i ve got some data...for testing its good I think.. and thats wouldnt be the problem for me isnt it? ..